# jQuery transition not run on anon page

Tags: javascript

I am running Drupal 8.5.5 and am running into a problem. It seems for anonymous users jQuery is not loading a library that it would when I am logged in as admin. I tried to understand why that is but I am stumped. So far I disabled js caching, I have the following in my libraries.yml:

```
leadership:
   version: 1.x
   css:
     theme:
        css/leadership.css: {}
   js:
      js/leadership.js: {}
   dependencies:
      - core/jquery: {}
```

and it loads on the page, and runs this javascript which calls:

```
$content.toggleClass("whole-body", 800);
```

In the admin, I see the transitional effect of 800 seconds, but anonymous users don't see that.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out, by just adding a bunch of jquery dependencies in my

> theme.libraries.yml

```
   js:
      js/leadership.js: {}
   dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/jquery.ui
    - core/jquery.ui.widget
    - core/jquery.ui.draggable
    - core/jquery.ui.mouse
    - core/jquery.ui.position
    - core/jquery.ui.resizable
```

once of the jquery ui was missing.